# How to read data from a file in C?

Tags: c, string

I have a file containing the information

```
0001:Jack:Jeremy:6:38.0
0002:Mat:Steve:1:44.5
0003:Jessy:Rans:10:50.0
0004:Van Red:Jimmy:3:25.75
0005:Peter:John:8:42.25
0006:Mat:Jeff:3:62.0
```

I want to get data from this file so each part of this string will have each value.
For example, `double num` will be 3; `char firstn[20]` will be 'Jack', `char lastn[20]` will be 'Jeremy', `int t` will be 6, and `double hour` will be 38.0, and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *read, *write;
    int i, group;
    double hours, num;
    char lastn[20],
         firstn[20];

    read = fopen("people.txt", "r");
    if (read == NULL) {
        printf("Error, Can not open the file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    write = fopen("people.dat", "w");
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        fscanf(read, "%lf:%s:%s:%d:%lf", &num, lastn, firstn, &group, &hours);
        fprintf(write, "Number: %lf Fname: %s Lastn: %s Group: %d Hours: %.1lf\n", num, lastn, firstn, group, hours);
    }
    fclose(read);
    fclose(write);

    return 0;
}
```

When I am trying to do so, my string `lastn` takes all the information until the end of line.

How can I specify so string `firstn` will take only characters until `:` and then string `lastn` will take only Jeremy, and group will take only 6, and so on?

Comment: yeah, its large assignment, but I have all the idea how to do everything else, but just stack with variables.

Comment: please tag homework questions as 'homework'

Comment: sorry bout that, didn't know that, will correct it right now.

Comment: is the format set? the %s operator breaks (automatically) on any whitespace character so if you were able to change the : to a space it should work.

Comment: unfortunately can't change it to space, have to be :

Comment: @twain249: changing from colon to space would break things on the line containing `Van Red`.  Using `:` separator is reasonable (as long as colon does not appear in the body of any field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your `fscanf()` format string.

```
if (fscanf(read, "%lf:%19[^:]:%19[^:]:%d:%lf", &num, lastn, firstn, &group, &hours) != 5)
    ...the read failed...
```

The notation `%19[^:]` means 'read up to 19 non-colon characters' into the string, followed by a null.  Note that the variables `lastn` and `firstn` are `char[20]`.  Note that the conversion is checked; if you get an answer other than 5, something went wrong.  You might consider scanning the rest of the line up to a newline after the `fscanf()` call:

```
int c;
while ((c = getc(read)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ;
```

You should also check that you succeeded in opening the output file.

Comment: That was the answer that I looked for! Thank, you ! very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets()` to read line and then tokenize it using `strtok()`

```
char line[100];
char *p;

fgets(line);
p = strtok(line, ":");
```

Now you can store tokens into variables as you like.

Comment: @Stanley Since you have ":" as delimiter, this is a nice way to tokenize it. The usual %s reads need whitespace as separator.

Comment: so what should be the syntax to read all the inforamtion from the line char line[100];
     char *p;

     fgets(&num, lastn, firstn, &group, &hours);
     p = strtok(line, ":");
like this?

Comment: I think strtok will faster than fscanf~

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
fscanf(read, "%lf:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf", &num, lastn, firstn, &group, &hours);
```

`%[^:]` means read a a string not including a colon.  See [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).